# How to show that $\int_{X}f\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{A}f\mathrm{d}\mu$ if $\mu(X\setminus A)=0$

Tags: measure-theory

Just a quick question. Apologies if it sounds dumb question. I am recently starting to learn about the basic measure theory. Suppose that $\mu$ is a measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$, and let $f$ be a function. If it is known that $A\in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(X\setminus A)=0$, how would you show that
$$
\int_{X}f\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{A}f\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
mathematically? The thing I am unsure about is to show that $\int_{X\setminus A}f\mathrm{d}\mu=0$. If there are some missing details, which conditions should there have been to make the above expression sense?

Comment: by definition of the integral of Lebesgue we have that $\int_{B}f \mathop{}\!d \mu =0$ for any chosen $B\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu (B)=0$ and any Lebesgue measurable function $f$

Comment: If $f$ is bounded, the integral is dominated by $\text{constant}\times\mu(X\setminus A)$. If it is not bounded, you can take an increasing sequence of the form $f_n = f\land n$ And use the Beppo Levi theorem. Alternatively, if you allow $0\times\infty=0$ (as often set in measure theory), simply the integral is dominated by $\sup(f)\times \mu(X\setminus A)$.

Comment: @Logos Assuming that it is not bounded, how would you use Beppo Levi's theorem, when we have a function $f$ that is not necessarily non-negative?

Comment: If $f$ is not bounded, the sequence $f_n = |f |\land n $ is an increasing sequence of positive functions which converges towards $|f|$. Now Beppo Levi’s Theorem is $f_n \uparrow |f| \Rightarrow \int_{X\setminus A}f_n d\mu \uparrow \int_{X\setminus A}|f| d\mu$. Since the sequence of integrals is zero, such is the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no loss of generality, suppose $f$ is positive. If not, work on $f^+$ and $f^-$ separately. If $f$ is positive, for each $n$ let us set $f_n = n \land f$. The sequence $(f_n)$ is increasing and converges towards $f$. Now if $\mu(X\setminus A) = 0$, then
$$
0 \le \int_{X\setminus A}f_n\,\mathrm d\mu \le \int_{X\setminus A} n\,\mathrm d\mu =n\mu({X\setminus A}) = 0 \Rightarrow \int_{X\setminus A} f_n\,\mathrm d\mu = 0.
$$
Applying Beppo Levi’s Theorem ($0\le f_n \uparrow f \Rightarrow \int f_n\,\mathrm d \mu \uparrow \int f\,\mathrm d \mu$):
$$
\int_{X\setminus A} f\,\mathrm d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{X\setminus A} f_n\,\mathrm d\mu = 0
$$

Comment: By $n\wedge f$, you mean that $\min\{n,f(x)\}$? If this is the case, how can it tend to $f$ as $n\to \infty$ pointwise?

Comment: Yes, it is the infimum (in this case also the minimum). The function $f_n$ coincides with $f$ when $f $ is smaller then $n$. When $n$ Increases, the limit tends to be $f$.

Comment: OK. I understand that $f_n=f$ if $f\geq n$. But does it always happen like that if $n$ gets higher? What if at some time $n$ will be greater than $f$?

Comment: Consider $c$ in $X$. Then $f(c)$ is a real number and by Archimedes principle, there exists a whole number $N$ Such that $f(c) > N$. Then for any $n$ greater than $N$, $f_n(c) = \min\{f(c),n\} = f(c)$ and therefore $f_n(c) \to f(c)$. Since this works for all $c$, then $(f_n)$ converges pointwise towards $f$.

Comment: If $f(c)\in \mathbb{R}$, doesn't Archimedes' property say that $N>f(c)$  for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, Archimedes’ Principle says that for each $x$ real, there exists a whole number $N$ Such that $x \le N$. Basically it states that each real number can be majorised by a whole number. Another way to say this is that if a real number is smaller of each natural number, then it is negative.

Comment: Yes, but in your case, you wrote that $f(c)$ is greater than $N$, i.e. $f(c)$ is not majorized by a whole number .. So, you meant $\leq$ instead of $>$ in your second comment

Comment: No, $f(c)$ needs to be smaller than $N$ so that the minimum is $f(c)$ and thwt is why the sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

What might be helpful is to unpack what it means to integrate over $X\backslash A$. Showing the equality in question is equivalent to saying that
$$\int_X fd\mu - \int_A fd\mu = 0$$
which is precisely the integral of $f$ over $X$ while excluding the set $A$. To see this, let $\mathcal{L}(S)$ be the set of linear combinations of indicator functions (functions that take 1 on a subset of $S$ and 0 off of it). Now first observe that:
$$\Big|\int_X fd\mu - \int_A fd\mu\Big| = \Big|\int_{X\backslash A} fd\mu\Big| \leq \int_{X\backslash A} |f|d\mu.$$
From here, we can bound this non-negative integral like so:
$$\int_{X\backslash A} |f|d\mu = \sup\Big\{\int_{X\backslash A}\phi : 0 \leq \phi \leq |f|,\phi\in \mathcal{L}(X\backslash A)\Big\} \leq \sup \phi \cdot \mu(X\backslash A) = 0$$
by the assumption that $\mu(X\backslash A) = 0$, hence proving the claim. I hope that was helpful!

Comment: I just want to make sure: is $\mathcal{L}(S)$ the set of simple functions defined on the set $S$?

Comment: Exactly, simple functions are defined as linear combinations of indicator functions.